# How do I stop this code from running if a single condition is not met PHP

Tags: php

This code still runs to the end and submit even if condition is not met. I want to stop it from running and echo an error if any condition is missed. Kindly help please. Note: I have tried exit() and it affected the whole html under from running.

```
  $verifiedPhone = phoneNumberValidator($phone);
    $correctsurname = nameValidator($surname);
    $correctlastname = nameValidator($lastname);
    $correctusername = nameValidator($username);
        if(!$verifiedPhone){
            echo "<p class='alert alert-warning'>Please use a Valid Phone Number</p>";

                            }
        if(!$correctsurname){
            echo "<p class='alert alert-warning'>Surname can only contain alphabets</p>";
                            }
        if(!$correctlastname) {
            echo "<p class='alert alert-warning'>Last Name can only contain alphabets</p>";
                            }
        if (!$correctusername) {
            echo "<p class='alert alert-warning'>Username can only contain alphabets</p>";
                            }
        $checkuser = "  SELECT * FROM staff
                        WHERE username = '$correctusername'";
        $checkuserresult = mysqli_query($connection, $checkuser);
        $checkuserrow = mysqli_num_rows($checkuserresult);
    if($checkuserrow > 0){
        echo "<p class='alert alert-danger'>Username \"".$username."\" already exist! Try another</p>";
                            }
  else{
        $harsedpassword = md5("$password");
  $datainsert = "   INSERT INTO staff (surname, lastname, phone, username, password) VALUES ('$correctsurname', '$correctlastname', '$verifiedPhone', '$username','$harsedpassword')";
 $datainsertresult = mysqli_query($connection, $datainsert);
  if($datainsertresult){
    echo "<p class='alert alert-success'><b>Staff Added Successfully</b></p>";
                                }
```

Comment: Use a flag variable. Toggle it when a condition is not met. Check for that flag variable before doing any action (e.g. db inserts).

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. I don't understand what you mean by flag variable and how to toggle it. I am a new baby in php.

Comment: `$flag = false;  if(!$correctusername) { echo ...; $flag = true; } ...more if's.... if(!$flag) { ...insert data...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use else ifs

```
if(!$correctsurname){
                        echo "<p class='alert alert-warning'>Surname can only contain alphabets</p>";
}
else if(!$correctlastname) {
                        echo "<p class='alert alert-warning'>Last Name can only contain alphabets</p>";
}
else if (!$correctusername) {
                        echo "<p class='alert alert-warning'>Username can only contain alphabets</p>";
}
else {
    //the rest
```

or die("message") if you must:

```
if(!$correctsurname){
                        die("<p class='alert alert-warning'>Surname can only contain alphabets</p>");
```

}

Comment: Thank man. You have solved my problem I rate you man. Thanks so much again

Comment: No prob - glad I could help!